# It's a little more than that

Tags: meaning

What does it mean when someone says:"It's a little more than that" and when we can say it.

Comment: It means that whatever was being discussed (_it_) is not exactly the same another thing (_that_): _it_ is something more that _that_. For example  "So John and Sue are friends? It's a little more than that." means that John and Sue are more than friends. The speaker probably means they are lovers.

Comment: it's most typically, I think, used around **dark or evil, or just bad** topics. not always, but usually.  (Women discussing a cheater: "Would you describe his actions as flirtation?" "It's a bit more than that...")  ("Look, it was like shoplifting..." "It's a bit more than shoplifting") (And so on...)

Comment: Who the heck would vote to close this? A non-native speaker?  it's an idiomatic phrase that is very subtle and needs explanation.

Comment: @JoeBlow I'm guessing the close voter wanted some actual work done on the part of the OP.

Comment: @Mitch: It's a little more than that.

Comment: Hi Mitch - I guess you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of understatement. It is said when what one really means is "**it's a lot more than that**," but wants to add more emphasis by using that rhetorical device.

About the best way to demonstrate would be to show how this bit of understatement is used to great effect in a film. The film I'm thinking of is *The Devil's Advocate*. Kevin Lomax (Keanu Reeves) asks John Milton (Al Pacino), who is actually Satan, who he is:

> **Lomax**: Who are you?
>   **Milton**: Who am I? Who are you? Never lost a case. Why? Why do you think?   'Cause you're so fuckin' good. Yeah? But why?
>   **Lomax**: Because you're my father.
>   **Milton**: I'm a little more than that, Kevin.

What Milton means, in the context of the film, is that he is the actual Prince of Darkness, Satan, Beelzebub, and all the titles that have been ascribed to that character throughout the ages. It couldn't be a bigger deal, but Milton lets the simple understatement work harder for him than a bold statement would have.

You can [view that part of the speech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1WdWH53nsu8&t=102) on YouTube. (Bonus: it's a lot of fun to watch the whole thing.)

Comment: Robu.  If you notice my comment under the op .. do you agree?  Maybe I'm off-base.

Comment: @JoeBlow: Not sure it's used mostly with dark or evil things (though it is in the example I gave), but those tend to be a great deal of what we talk about, so that may be where the perception comes from. It does seem to crop up when someone is discussing "the elephant in the room," which is often a negative.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from Zwi is fine. But sometimes it's a little more than that. The speaker can be using a rhetorical device known as **meiosis**...

> In rhetoric, meiosis is a euphemistic figure of speech that intentionally understates something or implies that it is lesser in significance or size than it really is. - *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiosis_%28figure_of_speech%29)*

...or just **understatement**. So it might mean something like-

> "Well... it's really really serious, but I can't come straight out with it here and now. I don't want to shock you, but you might get ready for something much more important than you thought..."

You can only tell from the context and tone of voice; but with this meaning, the phrase is often preceded with "well...". And you don't have to respond immediately since, having started down this route, the speaker is usually compelled to continue and "spill the beans" and you'll find out regardless.

Comment: It's almost more than a meiosis ... as I mention, it always suggests, i feel, a kind of dark velvet background, it's best for that sort of topic.

Comment: I know the word to describe what I'm saying ............ it's a **restrained** way to emphasise something, a strong power (often [but not always] negative, illegal, or bad in some way).

Comment: Oh, I was typing this while Robusto posted. All that work, and I'm pipped at the post. It's just one of those minor things, I suppose. (Actually, it's a little more than that).

Answer (score 1):

A - i think what happened is just an ordinary thing

B - really? i think it's a little more than that, it's more like a change for the better

used in order to accentuate a statement a bit

Comment: An excellent example of this usage I overheard:  "Jesus was a good man" "I think he was a little more than that..."  As I say, it's not so much understatement .. it's a rather "restrained" ... "lowering your voice" ... way to speak.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context.

If you're measuring something out, like flour for a cake, someone saying "It's a little more than that" is a non-precise way of saying more flour or more of an ingredient should be added.

A different context would be if someone has made an opinion or statement that is  showing very black and white opinions, with no nuance or complexity, the phrase "it's a little more than that" can mean the situation is more complex than the other person has implied, or it's more important, or more significant.

Comment: Certainly, the OP is referring to the idiomatic use.  An excellent question.